# When editing text in a UIList, is it possible to add behaviour of ex. Shift+Enter?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

In order to make a multi-line text entry widget out of a UIList, shortcut keys like Shift+Enter and Shift+Backspace could be useful in a UIList to either make a new list entry(new line) or collapse two list entries to one(one line), but how can special key assignments during text editing in a UIList be coded from python?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that using python, unfortunately.

Comment: I have tried to add a `"\n"` to the end of string using a modal function but some weird stuff was printed in ui :\